# EF core 5 how to populate navigation property without INCLUDE

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am not able to populate the navigation property automatically unless I use `Include()`. How do I automatically populate navigation property without `Include()`?

I am using EF core 5.0

```cs
Class customer
{
    [key]
    public int MappingID { get; set; } 
    public string MappingName {get;set;}
}

Class Order
{
    [key]
    public int orderID {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int MappingID { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey(nameof(MappingID))]
    public virtual customer customerMapping { get; set; }
}
```

This doesn't work. `customerMapping` comes back as `null` -

```cs
_context.Order.FirstOrDefault(x => x.orderID == 1);
```

This works. `customerMapping` gets populated -

```cs
_context.Order.Include(y => y.customerMapping).FirstOrDefault(x => x.orderID == 1);
```

Comment: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore5.com/lazy-loading-in-ef-core

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An owned type will always be included when the parent is loaded. This feature is implemented by setting a property in your model, which you can set by hand for any navigation.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .Navigation(d => d.customerMapping)
    .AutoInclude(true);
```

Comment: OP didn't mention anything about owned type.

Comment: No, but it was relevant to how I discovered the feature, I figured it might help other people discover the answer.

Comment: That's fine, but what if order and customer are in one-to-many? I know that is unlikely, but I really don't know.

Comment: The question was about loading a navigation property without an include. Which is possible, even for 1-many. But obviously has a performance impact if you don't always need that data.

Comment: @atiyar I have to agree with Jeremy. The `AutoInclude` feature is officially there since EFC 5.0 (and even before 5.0 via [SetIsEagerLoaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.mutablenavigationextensions.setiseagerloaded?view=efcore-3.1) - note, **public** metadata API). But for some unknown reason it is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation except the API itself. That's why not many people know about, and it is useful (and have been asked for in their GitHub)  in some scenarios. And can be turned off per query similar to global filters.

Comment: @IvanStoev I really have no disagreement with any of that or with Jeremy's sharing the feature. I myself too didn't know about it. Just was pointing that this works for owned type (if I didn't misinterpret the message), and we really don't know how OP's models are intended.

Comment: Is it possible to add this AutoInclude setting at a global level ?

Comment: You could enumerate all your navigation properties and set AutoInclude... But that would force EF to load your entire database into memory on every query.